# Java Spring form Validator to check whether a input string contains special characters or not

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I am trying to create a Java Spring form that checks whether the input string contains special characters or not. For example when a user types in a string containing special characters a message will pop up stating that the input string contains special characters.

My question is how to implement java function inside the validator to check for special characters in the input string?

Validator code

```js
package com.mkyong.customer.validator;

import org.springframework.validation.Errors;
import org.springframework.validation.ValidationUtils;
import org.springframework.validation.Validator;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import com.mkyong.customer.model.Customer;

public class CustomerValidator implements Validator{
 
 Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z0-9]*");
 String str = "userName";
 Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
 

 @Override
 public boolean supports(Class clazz) {
  //just validate the Customer instances
  return Customer.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz);

 }

 @Override
 public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {
  
  ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "userName",
   "required.userName", "Keyword is required.");
  
 }
 
  if (!matcher.matches()) {
         System.out.println("string '"+str + "' contains special character");
    } else {
         System.out.println("string '"+str + "' doesn't contains special character");
    }
 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot:

```
       String REGEX = "[^&%$#@!~]*";
       Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(REGEX);
```

And it should work fine. ^ outside the character class denotes start of line.

```
       String REGEX = "^[&%$##@!~]";
       String REGEX = "[^&%$#@!~]*";
```

^ inside a character class [] means a negation of the characters inside the character class.